# Ansible: How to build variable name using other variables values

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am Ansible newbie and I try to use a variable name that is composed by other variables

I have all.yml file in group_vars directory that contains following variables:

```
device_name: nycisco
remote_site: sydney
nycisco_ipsec_sydney: 10.10.10.10
```

In my playbook, I would like to be able to display **nycisco_ipsec_sydney** variable using **device_name** variable and **remote_site** variable.

I've tried following :

```
- name: Display remote peer IP address
  debug: msg="{{ device_name + '_ipsec_' + remote_site }}"
```

but it returns "nycisco_ipsec_sydney", instead of expected variable value 10.10.10.10 I want to be displayed.

I don't understand because when i try:

```
- name: Display remote peer IP address
  debug: msg="{{ nycisco_ipsec_sydney }}"
```

it returns correctly 10.10.10.10.

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve by the below code

```
  vars:
    app: xxx
    xxx_header: this is a new variable

  - debug:
    msg: "{{vars[app + '_header']}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Indeed your solution works fine when vars are located in the playbook. However, in my case, where vars are located in a separate .yml file, it's not working.

Comment: Even I have tried with {{app}} being passed as extra-vars and {{xxx_header}} is present under group_vars/all.yml. Still it works. Can you let me know the error and how you are trying it?

Comment: Hello Asha,
Here is below my group_vars/all.yml containing my variables :

    nycisco:
      ipsec_sydney: 10.10.10.10

Here's below code in my playbook:

    - name: Display remote peer IP address
      debug: msg="{{ device_name[ 'ipsec_' + remote_site] }}"

Then I am populating device_name var and remote_site var via a Tower survey.

When I launch playbook, i end up with following issue :

FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute u'ipsec_sydney'

Comment: Yes, with your code I am getting the same error, but when i give as msg: "{{vars[device_name + '_ipsec_' + remote_site]}}", i get the output as ok: [localhost] => {    "msg": "10.10.10.10"}. Can you please try the exact same one? ( please add underscore before and after ipsec)

Comment: Hi Asha, yes this one works when i have got variables on a single line... when I try to use variables with dict (like stated in my previous command) it doesn't work and I've got the following error message : " ({{vars(device_name['ipsec_' + remote_site]) }}): 'dict' object is not callable"}. Thanks a lot for your help anyway, I will choose either your solution or my solution using lookup module to be able to move on.

Answer (score 0):

try definining a temp var assigning it with the following value

```
var="{{ device_name }}_ipsec_{{ remote_site }}"
```

then print out the msg like this:

```
msg="{{ var }}"
```

it might be, that you have to put the different {{ }} under quotes, i'm not 100% sure about this.

another example from our project would be:

```
remote_home: "{{ansible_env.HOME}}"
jboss_home: "{{remote_home}}/example/jboss-project"
```

hope that helps.

edit: another solution

Comment: did it work? if so i'd appreciate it if you upvote/accept my answer. 
thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply !
I've tried your solution but unfortunately it returns also "nycisco_ipsec_sydney" and not the variable value.

I've also tried 

    msg="{{ {{ device_name }}_ipsec_{{ remote_site }} }}"

But this one ends up with an error.

Comment: edited my previous question with a possible solution. 
try creating a temporary variable from device_name + _ipsec_ + remote_site 
and then setting the message to {{ name_of_temp_var }} 

not sure if it works, but it might be worth a shot. unfortunately i don't have a device with ansible installed at my disposal at the moment, so i cannot try and verify it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve the issue using lookup module.
Following code returns correctly **nycisco_ipsec_sydney** variable value which is 10.10.10.10.

```
msg="{{ lookup('vars', device_name + '_ipsec_remote_' + remote_site) }}"
```